# How to remove commas from number

Tags: postgresql

When I run this query in postgres :

```
select id, name from schema.table;
```

I get this output
[image]
In this the id number comes with commas. Because of this, when i download this file to .csv format, I have format issues in the .csv file. How to handle this ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: does sign left to `id` column name on image mean id is `int[]`?.. what's the table table structura at all?..

Comment: In table structure id column is of type int8.

The integers listed in the left are autogenerated by postgres. It won't be present in the downloaded file.

Comment: postgres does not store commas (or decimal points) with numbers. The commas you are seeing are added by the application _displaying_ those numbers. You need to find out how to configure your application to display numbers in a different way.

Comment: ah - DOWLOAD csv! I though you have it when COPY to csv

Answer (score 0):

You should't have any coma in your integer *id* values since postgres does not store neither comas nor dots as numeric separators.

However, you may use the function `ltrim` to remove comas from string fields:

```
select ltrim(cloumn1, ','), column2 from schema.table
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html